# loading phpMyAdmin-database to UITableView

Tags: mysql, database, uitableview, phpmyadmin, xcode4.3

I developed an App in xcode 4.2 that reads data from a `phpMyAdmin` database and loads it to a tableview. Now if I do the same in`xcode 4.3`, it doesn't work anymore. I am looking for a solution since days now, but can't find any and I have no idea why it doesn't work (my database and php script works fine).

FirstViewController.h:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;

FirstViewController.m:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];    
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;    
    myArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions     
        error:&error];    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{  
    return [myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *info = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Message"];    

    return cell;
}
```